# i can`t download Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, browsers

i can`t download Tor browser.when i tried to enter it blocks[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP may be blocking it. Try GitHub
https://github.com/TheTorProject/gettorbrowser/blob/master/README.md